# Can an App Extension be opened before the updated app has been opened for the first time?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios-app-extension, ios-app-group

I am implementing App Extensions in an upcoming release of my app. In the main app, I update the data and move the PersistentStore (.sqlite file) to a shared App Group directory. I am concerned the the user might update the app and then attempt to use the App Extension before actually opening the updated app. This could cause major problems (for the way I am currently thinking the extension will be set up, at least). Is this something that could happen, or does an extension not appear in the list until the app has been opened at least one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app extension exists, it will be available to the user. There's no built in first-run check. It would be OK for your extension to detect that the app had not been run and tell the user that they need to go there first. It would be better if the app extension could handle the initial setup, but that's not always possible.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I suspected, so I am going to make sure to handle this and test all cases.